# Access XML import: Add foreign key to child table

Tags: xml, ms-access

I have An XML File that I want to import in MS-access. The problem is that it has multiple nested nodes which means access creates a new table for every different type of node. Now the problem is we cannot create any relationship between different tables, We can't even decipher their relationship in the database. Is there is anyway to solve this problem? The xml is generated by a software I use. A sample XML Data that will cause the type of problem I am facing:

```
<Envelope>
    <Sale>
        <CustomerName>a</CustomerName>
        <InvoiceNo>1</InvoiceNo>
        <item>
            <ItemName>I1</ItemName>
            <QTY>10</QTY>
            <Amount>25</Amount>
        </item>
        <item>
            <ItemName>I2</ItemName>
            <QTY>15</QTY>
            <Amount>14</Amount>
        </item>
    </Sale>
    <Sale>
        <CustomerName>b</CustomerName>
        <InvoiceNo>2</InvoiceNo>
        <item>
            <ItemName>I3</ItemName>
            <QTY>10</QTY>
            <Amount>72</Amount>
        </item>
        <item>
            <ItemName>I4</ItemName>
            <QTY>21</QTY>
            <Amount>43</Amount>
        </item>
    </Sale>
    <Sale>
        <CustomerName>c</CustomerName>
        <InvoiceNo>3</InvoiceNo>
        <item>
            <ItemName>I5</ItemName>
            <QTY>13</QTY>
            <Amount>53</Amount>
        </item>
        <item>
            <ItemName>I6</ItemName>
            <QTY>37</QTY>
            <Amount>27</Amount>
        </item>
    </Sale>
    <Sale>
        <CustomerName>d</CustomerName>
        <InvoiceNo>4</InvoiceNo>
        <item>
            <ItemName>I7</ItemName>
            <QTY>45</QTY>
            <Amount>67</Amount>
        </item>
        <item>
            <ItemName>I8</ItemName>
            <QTY>12</QTY>
            <Amount>98</Amount>
        </item>
    </Sale>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: maybe post your current table design and where you would like to import the XML into.. that might help to understand the expected output

Comment: There is no designs as the access creates the design at import itself. You could recreate the problem by importing the attached xml file in acces and you will see that there are two different tables created and will understand what the problem is.

Comment: By looking at your XML, it will produce at least two tables, one for scale and one for items.. now what are you trying to achieve? what/where is your destination table?

Comment: I want to be able to create a relationship between the two tables. while importing the file no relationships are made and if the xml file is huge it becomes impossible to create relationships after import

Comment: Add new column in your item node [invoice nr] and Copy the sale invoice nr value. This is a invoice to items relationship.

Comment: That's the problem. This are just 4 records. the data I have to deal with is of 1000's of records with atleast 50 different fields with 8 different tables being created. It wont be  possible to do it personally for all of them, right?

Comment: you can pharse the xml, read node by node and perform insertion.

Comment: any non-programming method?

Comment: non programming method? type it manually!!!!!

Comment: Just to confirm: Can [InvoiceNo] serve as the primary key (unique identifier for each row) of the [Sales] table?

Comment: Yes. Invoice number can be considered as primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [InvoiceNo] can serve as the primary key of the [Sale] table then all you need to do is perform an *XML Transform* to add [InvoiceNo] to the [item] table while importing. If you save the following as "LinkItemsToSales.xslt" ...

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <item>
            <InvoiceNo><xsl:value-of select="../InvoiceNo"/></InvoiceNo>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then you can use the "Transform..." button on the "Import XML" dialog to specify that file as the transform you want to apply. When the import is completed the [InvoiceNo] will appear in the [item] table like this:

```
InvoiceNo  ItemName  QTY  Amount
---------  --------  ---  ------
1          I1        10   25    
1          I2        15   14    
2          I3        10   72    
2          I4        21   43    
3          I5        13   53    
3          I6        37   27    
4          I7        45   67    
4          I8        12   98
```

Comment: How to concatenate two fields in one for the child node? i.e. how to use the concatenation of invoice name and customer name for child node?